# Using PowerShell to check if a Power BI file is damaged

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to check with PowerShell if a local Power BI report is damaged or not.

I mean by "damaged" that you receive the following error when you try to open the report:
[image]

(Document cannot be opened - Report cannot be opened. The file is either encrypted or damaged.)

Is there a way to do this?

A workaround could be to use the following command taken from ["ReportingServicesTools"](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/0.0.6.7):

```
Write-RsRestCatalogItem -WebSession $session -Path $PowerBIReportFilePath -RsFolder $RsFolderName -Overwrite $true
```

However, I do not want to upload any file before I check if it is damaged or not. Maybe with the use of a try/catch block, I can check if a report is damaged or not. If the command fails to upload the file and the script runs into the catch block, the file is probably damaged. Still, this workaround seems to be quite impractical for just checking if a report is damaged or not. There should be a more handy solution.

How I have created an exemplary damaged file:
I opened Power BI Desktop and saved a (blank) report as a file.
Then, I opened this file with a Texteditor, deleted one character and saved the file.

Comment: The only arbiter of whether a Power BI report is valid is Power BI. Since a .pbix is just a zip file, you can verify if it would extract correctly using PowerShell, but this is merely a necessary condition for validity, not a sufficient one. (Deleting a file from the zip would likely also result in an error, for example.)

Comment: Also, why would the files be damaged in the first place? That shouldn't be a very common scenario.

Comment: I know that it is not a very common scenario. However, sometimes the customer does strange things and PowerShell should tell him that his report is damaged before he sends this file to someone else.

Comment: In that case, an easy test is to use [expand-archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.1) to see if it throws an error